# CytoscapeJS in create-react-app not firing console.log

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, cytoscape.js

I use `Cytoscape.js` with `create-react-app`. The terminal is running the app but is not outputting `console.log`. Especially in the `handleClick` method.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Cs from 'cytoscape'
const { cyConfig, cyStyle } = require('./config/config')

class Graph extends Component {
  componentDidMount () {
    cyConfig.container = document.getElementById('cy')
    this.cy = Cs(cyConfig)
  }

  handleClick () {
    this.cy.on('tap', 'node', (e) => {
      const node = e.target
      console.log(node.id())
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div
        style={cyStyle}
        id='cy'
        onClick={ (e) => this.handleClick(e) }
      />
    )
  }

}

export default Graph
```

Comment: The docs look quite different to your approach. have you tried using [this](https://github.com/plotly/react-cytoscapejs) code to initialize cytoscape.js? Also, the problem might come from the ```this``` key, try the debugger to see if this refers to the right property.